# Spark Submit fails - /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/spark-class: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera

I'm doing following Cloudera Tutorial and doing "4. Submit the application using spark-submit". What I do wrong so that running tutorial fails? I find spark-shell and spark-submit, but not Spark-slass from /bin folder.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_streaming.html#streaming

```
 export SPARK_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH"

spark-submit --master local[2] --conf 
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" --jars 
$SPARK_HOME/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar kafka_wordcount_keke.py k 
localhost:2181 POCTopicKeke1


[Myadmin@Myclouderadatahub-mn0 lib]$ spark-submit --master local[2]  --jars $SPARK_HOME/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar kafka_wordcount_keke.py localhost:2181 POCTopicKeke1
/log/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/bin/../lib/spark/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/spark-class: No such file or directory
/log/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/bin/../lib/spark/bin/spark-submit: line 27: exec: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/spark-class: cannot execute: No such file or directory
[Myadmin@Myclouderadatahub-mn0 lib]$
```

Comment: Your link is for CDH 5.5... You're using 5.12

Comment: You can find the latest documentation at https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/spark_streaming.html#streaming

Comment: Do you mean that SPARK_HOME is pointing to wrong path? Does it make difference with spark-submit command if CHH version is 5.12?

Comment: It might not be able to find something  considering Spark 2 is now included.... Also, if you look at the output, it says `/log/cloudera/parcels/`, not `/opt/cloudera/parcels/`

Comment: In any case, you can can run `sudo find / -name spark-class -type f` to determine if that missing file really does exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar issue with CDH 5.13 and Spark2.2

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/bin/../lib/spark2/bin/pyspark: line 77: /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

Upon investigating I found that I set SPARK_HOME manually in `/etc/profile` to

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2
```

and even after commenting it and reloading the `/etc/profile` it didn't work.

**Solution**:

`env` command displayed that `SPARK_HOME` was still set ( strange ) so I unset the `SPARK_HOME` using following command

`unset SPARK_HOME`

and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Facing similar issue with Spark 2.4.4:

```
bin/spark-submit --version
bin/spark-submit: line 27: /some/path/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
/some/path/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: No such file or directory
bin/spark-submit: line 27: exec: /some/path/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
/some/path/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Solution: define SPARK_HOME (which for me was not defined)

```
export SPARK_HOME=/some/path/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Meeting the same issue with spark on CDH.

The key of the problem is that CDH has Already specified the SPARK_HOME  direction on its spark-env.sh. It will overrides detected the linux environment variables.

In the case that the company not allow to use "/opt" installing CDH's spark client. It should change the HADOOP_HOME and SPARK_HOME on spark-env.sh .

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/Unionpay_Xzb/CDH/lib/spark

SPARK_PYTHON_PATH=""
if [ -n "$SPARK_PYTHON_PATH" ]; then
  export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$SPARK_PYTHON_PATH"
fi

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/Unionpay_Xzb/CDH/lib/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME="$HADOOP_HOME"
```

User-defined SPARK_HOME overrides detected will not happen！